# jq — Extract strings contained in nested arrays and objects

Tags: jq

I have this jq filter and input:

```
( ._birthDate.extension[0] | .url, ( .extension[0] | .url, .valueString ), ( .extension[1] | .url, .valueString ) )
```

```json
{
   "_birthDate":{
      "extension":[
         {
            "url":"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-dataBirhtDeath",
            "extension":[
               {
                  "url":"country",
                  "valueString":"724"
               },
               {
                  "url":"state",
                  "valueString":"08"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

…which yields the following output:

```json
"http://catsalut.gencat.cat/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-dataBirhtDeath"
"country"
"724"
"state"
"08"
```

I wanted to refactor the filter:

```
( ._birthDate.extension[0] | .url, ( .extension[:2] | .url, .valueString ) )
```

…but I am getting the following error:

> jq: error (at :18): Cannot index array with string "url"

See this [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PUObKuVqhQ).

Comment: Instead of linking to external sites, please paste the JSON here. Also, do you expect to get the same output as in the first case?

Comment: The expression `.extension[:2]` generates an array, whereas you expecetd the array elements. Thus, simply iterate over the elements instead:  `.extension[:2][]`

Comment: @choroba. I've added json on post. Yes, I'm expecting the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Array/String Slice: `.[10:15]` <sup>[[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice)]</sup>
>
> ... Either index may be negative (in which case it counts backwards from the end of the array), **or omitted (in which case it refers to the start or end of the array)**.

So your were first using `.extension[0]` that ment: take index `0` from `.extension` where

`.extension[:2]` means: take index `0` **up and including** index `2` from `.extension`

---

As [@pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168107/jq-work-with-array-iterations-in-mapping-expression#comment124038404_70168107) already mentiond, the difference is the returned value, an object at first, but an array on the second.

So you can loop over the array using `[]` to return the `.url` and `.valueString` for each object in side the `.extension` array:

```
._birthDate.extension[0] | .url, ( .extension[:2][] | .url, .valueString )
```

<sup>[Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/E84lNNpF_V)</sup>

---

However, since `.extension` is an array with only 2 indexes, the `:2` part doesn't do anything useful in your example, so why not simplify it to:

```
._birthDate.extension[0] | .url, ( .extension[] | .url, .valueString )
```

<sup>[Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bNauNSCwTd)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to keep the strings then you can use `..` to recursively traverse your document and `strings` to filter out non-strings yielded along the way:

```
.. | strings
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ztaZHg92ll)